# Open Excel Workbook with vba code - error to notify VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vba

I am trying to open an Excel file from my C# code.

```
workBook = workBooks.Open(fileName,               //filename
                          0,                      //updatelinks
                          true,                   //readonly
                          5,                      //format
                          "",                     //password
                          "",                     //WriteResPassword
                          true,                   //IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended
                          XlPlatform.xlWindows,   //Origin
                          "\t",                   //Delimiter
                          false,                  //Editable
                          false,                  //Notify
                          0,                      //Converter
                          true,                   //AddToMru
                          1,                      //Local
                          0);                     //CorruptLoad
```

I see that the code hangs at **workBooks.Open** if the excel has some error within it.
I have kept the display property to true and that is when I noticed that there is an error in the excel. On further investigation I got to know that the error is caused due to some vba code in the excel which is failing. My requirement is how do I get my C# code to be notified about this, so that it can ignore the error within the file or ignore the file itself?

Comment: For the uninitiated, maybe some `// comments` inline to describe what each of the 400 arguments are for? Not your fault of course, but ugh, that's some signature...

Comment: In .Net4 with named parameter you can pass parameter in better way, interop is really ugly:(, anyway, doesn't this throw any exception? in bad circumstances?

Comment: @Saeed, Thanks..Interop is indeed very ugly. I am struggling a lot with it. It does not throw any exception. Just hangs!!! Do you have any idea how to do this in 4.0. I believe it would internally use the Interop. But would be more than happy if it can manage it in a clean manner!!!

Comment: Nishat see [named parameter and interop in .net4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) or [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) do not need comments, Also for your problem, In fact I don't have an good idea, but some crazy way is open it in another thread and if takes more time finish it :))

Comment: Try tinkering with the Application.AutomationSecurity property.  You'll want the 'ForceDisable' setting.

Answer (score 1):

What do you try to achive? Maybe just using the Microsoft Open XML SDK would be enough?
You can read, create and edit Excel files with it.

Comment: I would like to fetch all the named ranges in the excel file. Is it possible with Open XML?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to using the intreop library is http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/  which  doesn't require you to have excel or the excel.dll installed and registered to your machine or server that you are putting it on.